# Power Series Differential Equation evaluation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I'm trying to evaluate the solution to the following differential equation using power series:$$y''+y'+x^2y=0$$
and I got the following values to substitute:
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^n$$
$$y'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nC_n x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)C_{n+1} x^n$$
$$y''=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)C_n x^{n-2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(n+2)C_{n+2} x^n$$

and after I substitute I get

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty [(n+1)(n+2)C_{n+2}+(n+1)C_{n+1} ] x^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty C_nx^{n+2}=0$$

I got an expression for $C_{n+2}=\frac {-C_1}{(n+2)!}$
But $C_n$ does not seem to equate anything. Does this imply $C_n =0$?Or am I going wrong with this?

Comment: No, it doesn't imply that C(n)=0. Rather, it means that C(n) will have a defined value (this you would get from the boundary values), for a particular value of n and the rest of the coefficients will simply follow this recursive relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means that :

$$(2c_2+c_1)x^0+(6c_3+2c_2)x^1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\Big[(n+1)(n+2)c_{n+2}+(n+1)c_{n+1}+c_{n-2}\Big]x^n =0, \forall x $$

And then you can identify the terms

Comment: Thanks a lot @NHL..I'll evalaute it and let you know how it turns out!

Comment: The solution worked out just fine....I got the result...Thank you @NHL!!